# How to change mat-icon when i click?

Tags: angular

I use mat-menu in Angular and I want to change mat-icon if I click, but things aren't working as I expected. What could I be doing wrong?

This is my app.html:

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" >
  <mat-icon (click)="changeIcon()">{{icon}}</mat-icon>
</button>

<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <span>Log in</span>
  </button>
  <button mat-menu-item>
    <span>Register</span>
  </button>  
</mat-menu>
```

and my app.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  icon = 'more_vert';

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  changeIcon() {
    if (this.trigger.menuClosed) {
      this.icon = 'more_vert';
      console.log('fermer');
    }
    if (this.trigger.menuOpened) {
      this.icon = 'close';
      console.log('ouvert');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you trace into the `changeIcon` method, what do you see? Are the values of `this.trigger.menuClosed` and `this.trigger.menuOpened` what you expect? Are you sure that `changeIcon()` is going to be called **after** the menu state (open/closed) is updated?

Comment: mat-icon-close display  at the first click and stay displayed

Comment: put the (click) in the button, not in the icon < button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"  (click)="changeIcon()">< mat-icon>{{icon}}< /mat-icon>
  < /button>

Comment: I have already tried without success.  I think that this.trigger.menuOpened does not work. But the documentation says to use it

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution. other proposals ?

app.html

```
<button mat-icon-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (click)="changeIcon()" #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" >

    <mat-icon>{{icon}}</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false">
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <span>Log in</span>
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>
      <span>Register</span>
    </button>

  </mat-menu>
```

and app.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { MatMenuTrigger } from '@angular/material/menu';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit  {
  @ViewChild(MatMenuTrigger) trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

icon = 'more_vert';

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {

}


changeIcon() {
  this.trigger.menuClosed.subscribe(() => this.icon = 'more_ver');
  this.trigger.menuOpened.subscribe(() => this.icon = 'close');

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd add this since this entry came up when I was searching for something similar.

You could drop your `(click)="changeIcon()"` within the markup, and just stick with setting it up in the .TS file (letting your Subscribes do the work):

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.changeIcon();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could drop your `(click)="changeIcon()"` within the markup, and just stick with setting it up in the `.ts` file (letting your Subscribes do the work);
and call in ngonInit();

```
ngonInit(){
  this.changeIcon()
}
```